# jQuery Get HTML of Children except Child Element X

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

How can jQuery/Javascript be used to select the HTML of the two `<p>` elements in the first `<div class="description`? Regex is fine too. This jQuery selection is actually done within Node.js on a `cheerio` object.

Using

```
$( $('.description')[0] ).children().not('h2').html()
```

seems to only grab the text

```
Foo Bar
```

instead of

```
<p>Foo</p> 
<p>Bar</p>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='description'>
  <h2>Hello world</h2>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Bar</p>
</div>

<div class='description'>
  <h2>Goodbye world</h2>
  <p>Didi</p>
  <p>Deedee</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".description").eq(0).children().slice(1)` will get you the actual nodes but not the tags. Why do you want the tags too?

Comment: @thedarklord47 Yes I want the tags too

Comment: may help  ..http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4ef5g3h1/

Comment: @thedarklord47 I'm scraping a webpage and want to keep the formatting tags such as `b` `i` `br`. On the original webpage, `<p>` is used to define paragraphs, without the `<p>` the text will all combine into a large paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

If you deconstruct your jQuery statement, you get the following:

```
$('.description')[0]
```

will return your first that first `<div>` node.

```
$( $('.description')[0] ).children()
```

will return an array of all the children of that `<div>` node, so that's an array with three nodes, an `<h2>` and two `<p>`.

```
$( $('.description')[0] ).children().not('h2')
```

will return the same array as above, minus the `<h2>`.

```
$( $('.description')[0] ).children().not('h2').html()
```

will apply `.html()` to each of these nodes, i.e. extract all of the html inside the node. And inside `<p>Foo</p>` is `Foo`.

This is what you're looking for:

```
$( $('.description')[0] ).children().not('h2').prop('outerHTML')
```

**Update:** based on the [Cheerio docs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio): you would need to do this:

> If you want to return the outerHTML you can use $.html(selector):

So, in your case, I would try:

```
$( $('.description')[0] ).children().not('h2').html('p')
```

Comment: Does Cheerio have an "outerHTML" prop? I don't think it simulates the whole DOM.

Comment: that's going to change the html of the selector to 'p'

Answer (score 3):

You can create a duplicate element and remove everything you don't want, or do it on your original if you don't need to access the `h2` later.

```
var dup = $(".description").clone();
dup.children("h2").remove();
var out = dup.html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Update :

As per the documentation, you may try the following :

```
$.html($('.description:first').children(':not(h2)'));
```

Comment: Same as Olivier's answer, same problem.

Comment: outerHTML is an attribute of the DOM element and does not have any impact from external js api's

Comment: this is server-side JavaScript and Cheerio has a very stripped-down DOM

Answer (score 0):

You can use a neater approach by `.prop("tagName")` in jQuery.